# Allowing the user to edit a UIImage

Tags: uiimage, uiimagepickercontroller, edit

I have let the user select an image using UIImagePickerController.
The resulting image is shown in a UIImageView.
There is a UIButton below the image with the title "Edit Image".
My question is, How or to where to i present modal view controller to allow the user to edit the image?

This code allows the user to edit the image s/he has chosen...

```
UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
imagePicker.delegate = self;
imagePicker.allowsEditing = YES;
imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;

[self presentModalViewController:imagePicker animated:YES];
```

... but i want the user to be able to edit this image after s/he has picked it as well.

How would i go about doing this?

Perhaps a screen like this:

[image]